# Parsing Json to object giving "null" Value

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

Unable to parse this json data to object. Same code i tried with other URL, working correct. Please Suggest where i am doing wrong?

```
-(void)callAPI{
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:s.json"]];
    NSError *error=nil;
    id response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                 NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        NSLog(@"%@",response);}}
```

Output **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

Comment: Brother see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the very perfect solution for your question which works fine now.Please check the below answer

```
- (void)callAPI 
{

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2iodh4vg0eortkl/facts.json"]];
  [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * data,
    NSURLResponse * response,
    NSError * error) {
      NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"jsonString is: %@", jsonString);
      NSData *dataCon = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      id jsonVal = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataCon options:0 error:nil];
      if([jsonVal isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
          NSLog(@"The response starts with NSDictionary");
          NSArray *arrJsonVal = [jsonVal objectForKey:@"rows"];
          NSMutableArray *arrTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
          NSMutableArray *arrDesc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
          NSMutableArray *arrImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
          for(NSDictionary *dict in arrJsonVal) {
              NSString *strTitle = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
              NSString *strDesc = [dict objectForKey:@"description"];
              NSString *strImage = [dict objectForKey:@"imageHref"];

              [arrTitle addObject:strTitle];
              [arrDesc addObject:strDesc];
              [arrImage addObject:strImage];
          }
          NSLog(@"arrTitle is - %@",arrTitle);
          NSLog(@"arrDesc is - %@",arrDesc);
          NSLog(@"arrImage is - %@",arrImage);

      }else {
          NSLog(@"The response starts with NSArray");
      }
  }] resume];

}
```

The Printed results are

[image]
 [image]

After that

[image]

Then Array results  are

[image]
[image]

Finally the results are

[image]